# Can WinUSB be used to communicate with any USB device?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, libusb, winusb

Is there a way to determine whether or not I can use WinUSB with any given device?

I am attempting to see if I can use libusb with USB3 Vision devices. This is the first time I have ever tried to communicate with a USB device so I am having some difficulties.

From libusb's site I know that it requires using WinUSB as the driver for the device. It also seems like WinUSB is a safe bet for a lot of devices, but I am having a hard time finding out whether WinUSB can be used with USB3 Vision devices.

Since I wasn't able to find a direct yes or no online, I tried using [Zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) to install WinUSB, with no luck. I have also tried making a custom inf file and trying to install the WinUSB driver through the device manager. Obviously I haven't had much luck.

I know that USB3 Vision is relatively new, so I know there might not be many people out there who have tried doing anything similar. So I am wondering if it is worth it to continue trying to install WinUSB as a driver for the device. Is there some way of knowing for sure that it will or will not work with my device?

---

**Update:**

The device doesn't seem to have any compatible ID's in its Details section (Device Manager -> Right click on *Device* -> *Properties* -> *Details*).
Is it possible that the lack of a WinUSB Compatible ID means it isn't compatible for sure?

Comment: There's a fairly heavy disconnect here, of course the ID is unknown.  If it wasn't then you'd have a device driver for the device and wouldn't need to tinker with WinUSB.  It does little, it just gives you access to the raw control and data transfers to the device.  A glorified serial port.  Exactly what they mean is up to you to figure out.  Realistically you cannot do that without documentation from the manufacturer.  Normally pretty hard to get, but if they don't supply a driver then you ought to be able to shame them into releasing it to you.

Comment: @HansPassant They do release a driver along with an SDK to access the camera, but I am more interested in being able to use any USB3 Vision camera not just a specific manufacturers camera. So I'm trying to find a more general way to talk with the camera so that I might also be able to do the same with other manufacturers. I know there must be a way since USB3 Vision cameras are part of the [Genicam Standard](http://www.emva.org/cms/index.php?idcat=27). The problem I am having is trying to find a way to talk to any of those cameras over their USB3 connections.

Comment: That looks like an application interface standard, not a bus standard.  It doesn't just cover USB.  If that's accurate then fuggedaboutit.

Comment: So does that mean that I would be best off making my own proper driver to communicate with these cameras, @HansPassant ?

Comment: It means that you have to do this for *every* device, all of them different.  That's not "best off" of course.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for helping me understand this situation a bit more :)